# Front Product List Grid in Custom Module

Tags: php, magento

I need to display a collection in the front-end of magento like the grid shown to list products for a particular category by default.

I want the grid in a custom module to display a custom collection with all the features of pagination and sorting.

Please help me.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. No one is going to build a custom module for you and post it as an answer.

Comment: I am not asking anybody to build a custom module... I just want a explanation on how to implement the product listing grid that is used by magento by default. Secondly I never asked anyone to build a module for me... I am capable of doing that by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml, you have something like :

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

It sets everything for a list of product, you can reuse it with the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml and app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml... Additionnaly, there is layer/view.phtml that can be of an interest for you but with so few information, it is difficult to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Actually i need to display a list or grid of a custom collection that is used in my module. But instead of using my own pagination, sorting etc. I want to use the default grid like we use in the admin side of the magento store.

I have already tried the things that you have mentioned in your answer but got no positive success. Can you please look for it again and help me.

Comment: Is it for frontend or backend ?

Comment: The grid you described is specific to admin side that is a little bit lonely on the magento environment. Still you can call the according blocks to your module but I do not know how it will act as I never tried. In the other hand you can use the pager that is avaiable on frontend to paginate whatever you want with a few customization.